# Show that $\left|(z-h)^k-z^k\right|\leqslant Chz^{k-1}$

Tags: limits

Is anyone able to shed any light on how to proceed?

---

Show that $\left|(z-h)^k-z^k\right|\leqslant Chz^{k-1}$, where $C$ is some constant, $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $k\geqslant 1$.

---

By expanding the LHS, I get
$$
\left|z^k-{k\choose 1} z^{k-1}h+{k\choose 2} z^{k-2}h^2-{k\choose 3} z^{k-3}h^3+\dots\pm{k\choose k} z^{k-k}h^k-z^k\right|.
$$
Cancelling out the first and last terms and I can extract $h$,
$$
h\left|-{k\choose 1} z^{k-1}h+{k\choose 2} z^{k-2}h^2-{k\choose 3} z^{k-3}h^3+\dots\pm{k\choose k} z^{k-k}h^k\right|,
$$
which is bounded by
$$
h\left[{k\choose 1} z^{k-1}h+{k\choose 2} z^{k-2}h^2+{k\choose 3} z^{k-3}h^3+\dots+{k\choose k} z^{k-k}h^k\right].
$$

I am then unsure whether what I have done is correct.

I see that the above expression is bounded by
$$
h\left[{k\choose 1} \omega^{k-1}+{k\choose 2} \omega^{k-1}+{k\choose 3} \omega^{k-1}+\dots+{k\choose k} \omega^{k-1}\right],
$$
where $\omega=\max(z,h)$.

The expression hence becomes
$$
h\omega^{k-1}\sum_{l=1}^{k}{k\choose l}.
$$

For any given $k$, obviously the summation returns a constant, so I have my required $C$ and the form
$$
Ch\omega^{k-1}.
$$

I am unsure how to get from $\omega^{k-1}$ to $z^{k-1}$ as required by the question.

Comment: Hint: Use $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+\cdots +b^{n-1})$.

Comment: It is not true. Let $z=0$, then the above statement reduces to $|h^k| \le 0$ which is not true unless $h=0$.

Comment: @Babgen. That's brilliant, thanks.